# How to color the adjacent space of a centered column using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a design in Drupal, the layout like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUTiE.png

That is: one centered column having the header, navbar, body and footer. The left and right adjacent spaces are empty. Now, I need to fill the left and right space of sections 1, 2 and 3 with the same color, but without stretching the div. My idea was to create three divs (1', 2', 3', both left and right) and set the background-color accordingly.

That went fine with 1, but I can't match the height of div 2 (Tried everything, settings 'min-height' to html, to body, to container div, and nothing worked).

I was wondering if there is another way to achieve what I want, or what could be wrong with the problematic height.

Thanks!

Comment: can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have?

Comment: Are the boxes on the left going to contain content or are they just presentational?

Comment: Can you use background images?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using background images...http://dabblet.com/gist/2920146